# Finding peaks MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a vector which includes a gray levels of pixels in a one line of an image. `vec=IM(:,65);` 
I showed the parts of the array I want to detect. These parts will be my objects' piksels.

How can I detect these object pixels?

Plot of vec:
[image]
The vector is here:
[vec](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xenh8gm7fmk54la/array.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: did you try the `findpeaks`-method? It has parameters to filter, I would try 'MinPeakprominence' first

Comment: Agree with Daniel.  Use `findpeaks` on the negative of your data.

Comment: I'll write an answer soon if no one has written anything

Comment: Why did you change the question??

Comment: @MendiBarel I reverted it back. I hate when people do that. Our answers no longer make sense and this is after they accept an answer too.

Answer (score 6):

This can easily be solved using [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) from the Signal Processing Toolbox.  Specifically, for your data I had to call it this way:

```
[pks, locs] = findpeaks(max(vec)-vec, 'minpeakdistance', 160, 'minpeakheight', 22);
```

`findpeaks` only finds positive peaks (local maxima).  As such, what we need to do is invert this so that all of the local minima become local maxima.  I did this by taking the maximum value of the vector and subtracting with the vector.  Because there are so many local peaks, the `minpeakdistance` field allows you to find peaks that are at least separated by this much in between each peak.  I tuned this to 160.  Also, the minimum peak height finds peaks that are greater than a certain number, which I tuned to be 22.  `pks` finds the actual peak values and `locs` gives you the locations of the peaks in your signal.  We need to use `locs` to find the actual peak data because we performed this on the mirror reflected version of your signal.  As such, to get the actual peak data, do this:

```
pks_final = vecs(loc);
```

As a demonstration, let's plot this signal as well as the peaks that were located by `findpeaks`:

```
plot(1:numel(vec), vec, locs, vec(locs), 'r.');
```

The original data is plotted in blue while the detected peaks are plotted in red.  This is what I get:

[image]

---

Good luck!

Comment: @rayryend great idea. +1 for that. But one qn: why not findpeaks(-vec, 'minpeakdistance', 160, 'minpeakheight', 22); why need to max(vec)-vec?

Comment: @lakesh - Doing `-vec` would negate all values of the data, and `minpeakheight` only works for **positive** values.  If the data was centered at zero, then `-vec` would work, but observe that all of the points are above 0.  If you try your suggestion, you will get a warning specifying what I said, and you will find no peaks.

Comment: @lakesh - My pleasure.  Keep asking if you're confused!

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to find local peaks, here i use the deviation from the local average, then separating the regions, and scanning each region for minimum.

```
clear
close all

load a

std_a=std( a(a~=0) );

SMOOTH_SIZE=131;% depend on data size
THRESHOLD=0.7*std_a;

smooth_a = conv(a,ones(SMOOTH_SIZE,1)/SMOOTH_SIZE,'same'); %ma filter

deviation_a=a-smooth_a; 
negdev_a=deviation_a.*(deviation_a<-THRESHOLD); %deviation in negative region (minimum)

negdev_a_left=[negdev_a(2:end) 0]; % helper to find starting index point
negdev_a_right=[0 negdev_a(1:end-1)]; % helper to find end index point

negdev_a(1)=0; negdev_a(end)=0; % make sure that we have zero point
indfrom=find(negdev_a==0 & negdev_a_left~=0); %start index per region
indto=find(negdev_a==0 & negdev_a_right~=0); %start index per region

if(length(indfrom)~=length(indto)), error('error in regions');end

peak_indexes=zeros(1,length(indfrom)); %number of regions
peak_counter = 0;

for i=1:length(indfrom)
  [center_min, min_idx]=min( a( indfrom(i):indto(i) ) );
  real_min_idx=indfrom(i)-1+min_idx; % convert back to original array index
  if( real_min_idx==indfrom(i) || real_min_idx==indto(i) ), continue; end
  left_max=max(a( indfrom(i):real_min_idx-1)); %helper to check for real minimum
  right_max=max(a( real_min_idx+1:indto(i)));  %helper to check for real minimum

  if(center_min<left_max && center_min<right_max) % check if this is real minimum
       peak_counter=peak_counter+1;
       peak_indexes(peak_counter)=real_min_idx;
  end
     % if you need subpixel accuracy you can do some weighted average in the min region
end
peak_indexes=peak_indexes(1:peak_counter); %narrow to found indexes

figure; plot(a); hold on; plot(smooth_a, 'k'); hold off;
figure; plot(deviation_a);hold on;  plot(negdev_a,'r.');hold off;
figure; plot(a);hold on; plot(peak_indexes, a(peak_indexes),'rO');hold off; %result
```

[image: Result]
Hope this help,
Mendi

Comment: Can you show us what the results would be using your algorithm given the OP's data?  Can it find those peaks and **only** those peaks given in the OP's example?  Judging from your code, it finds all local peaks but does not isolate the desired peaks specified by the OP

Comment: Very nice!  Good job.  However, I do find it intrusive as you have to download an extra file that isn't part of native MATLAB.

Comment: Ok i removed the external file and added code for moving average filter.

Comment: A for-loop for a moving average, I'm dying ... no please, it tarnishes your solution. Use instead something like that: `smooth_a = conv(a,ones(SMOOTH_SIZE,1)/SMOOTH_SIZE,'same');`, way better and clearer.

Comment: It gives quite good results for me, thank you. A question, How did you decide the number 0.7 in line "THRESHOLD=0.7*std_a;"?