# Frequency domain from polar plot data

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I have coordinates of boundary of a picture (x,y) converted into polar plot (theta,rho) and now I need to work with data rho in frequency domain. Could someone advise how to do it, please? Here is my code and pictures:

[image: http://www.nahraj-obrazek.cz/?di=014245375032]                            [image: http://www.nahraj-obrazek.cz/?di=3142453758011]

```
BW=im2bw(I);
BWH=imfill(BW,'holes'); 
BWE=edge(BWH,'canny'); 
boundaries=bwboundaries(BWE); 
b=boundaries; x=b(:,2); y=b(:,1); 
% cartesian plot 
X=x-mean(x); 
Y=y-mean(y); 
THETA=X; 
RHO=Y; 
[THETA,RHO]=cart2pol(X,Y); 
% polar plot 
RHO1=smooth(RHO,10); 
% smoothing data 
plot(RHO1);
```

What it means frequency domain, is it through fft??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language/library/whatever?

Comment: yes..sorry! MATLAB image processing toolbox

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What data do you want to work with in the frequency domain?

Comment: data X,Y are coordinates of the boundary of the image, then were converted into polar coordinates (THETA,RHO).. RHO data were smoothed so I  need to work with RHO1 (the first plot above)

Comment: After I need detect peaks on the wave on this graph (RHO1)..

Comment: So if you want to do a peak detection on the first graph, then I'm going to provide you a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting FFT peaks from data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081942/getting-fft-peaks-from-data)

Comment: also possible duplicate of [Finding local low peaks of a vector. MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432883/finding-local-low-peaks-of-a-vector-matlab)