# Removing spikes from a signal Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, outliers, noise-reduction

I have the following signal which contains some distorted data

[image: Raw signal]

I'm trying to remove those spikes without damaging my signal, I've tried the `medfilt1` function but it smoothed out the correct signal as well which is not wanted. Filtering cannot be used because of the frequency overlap between the wanted and unwanted signal. I also tried a moving window which will compare the value with the median of this window and if the point is much higher than it it will set it to the median as shown bellow:

```
%moving cleaning window
y1_1= y1(1:100);%first window
 x=1;
 %cleaning loop
while  x<= length(y1)
    if(y1(x)> 1.01*(median(y1_1))||y1(x) < 0.95*(median(y1_1)))
        y1(x)= median(y1_1);
    end
    if(x>= length(y1)-100)
        y1_1= y1(length(y1)-100:length(y1));
    else
     y1_1 = y1(x:x+100);
    end
     x=x+1;
end
```

I've gotten rid of the spikes but also some of the signal's distinct peaks were gone as shown in the figure bellow

[image: Output of actual program]

How do I achieve the best denoising in a simple way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432883/finding-peaks-matlab/27439621#27439621

Comment: In **this specific case**, and only if this is **for presentation purposes**, it looks like you can just remove (or set to `NaN`) all values below about 350 and above 550.

Comment: Your code looks generally OK, though I would center window around the point I am interested in. Now you only need to play with window and conditions when to remove outliers. Try window of 30 and when the point is 2x or half the median. Or use findpeaks function instead and play with that one.

Comment: @Dev-il I can use that but my signal can have different levels (I'll be processing different signals). Ziizy archer, this might be a good idea, i'll try centering the point in the window and increasing ot's size. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use median filter or moving average filter. Whatever filter it is, you need to use some kind of threshold. Threshold the spikes and replace them with your filter result.

```
s=rand(500,1)*5; 
s(ceil(rand(1,20)*500))=rand(1,20)*100; 
maxs=max(s);

figure
subplot(211); plot(s);

thr=10;
med_s=medfilt2(s,[10,1]); 
s(s>med_s+thr)=med_s(s>med_s+thr);
subplot(212); plot(s); ylim([0 maxs])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to R2017a, you may want to check out the [`filloutliers`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filloutliers.html) function.  There are various methods you can use to detect the spikes, and similarly a variety of choices as to how to fill them.

If you want to basically get a median filter but only on the spikes, then you can specify `'movmedian'` as the find method and `'center'` as the fill method.

Comment: Thats a good idea, I might download the trial and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a MUCH smaller window. As  both neighboring values of the spike seem to be good representation of the true signal, a window of length 3 could solve your problem. In general, a longer window will distort more your signal.

Also, the computational cost will be greatly reduced with a smaller window.